# Syntax error: unexpected ''y'':

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to make a bit of a spawn point thing on Minecraft Xbox One, but whenever I type in the command

```
testfor @a [x=0 y=4 z=0 r=10]
```

it responds with

```
Syntax error: Unexpected "y": at "r @a [x=0 >>y<<=4 z=0 r=1"
```

Is there a simple, not-too-complicated way to solve this for someone who doesn't know much about JavaScript?

Comment: what if you add a comma after x=0 ?

Comment: That worked! Thanks, I didn't think of that. I just needed to add a comma after every coordinate

Comment: cool, let me post that as an actual answer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding commas to the command:

```
testfor @a [x=0,y=4,z=0,r=10]
```

Comment: The spaces are not needed either. With some other selector arguments, they might even cause issues.